# Ubuntu 16.04.1 freshly installed loops on login

Tags: login

As the title of the post says; I just installed the ***tested***  (thank goodness!) driver for my NVIDIA graphic card, then, when I rebooted, I was stuck in a login loop. What could I do?
Thanks in advance.

(sorry if my English isn't good. I'm not a native speaker)

Comment: That sounds more like a laptop with hybrid graphics. Please clarify what is the make of your Nvidia Graphics Card? Are you using a laptop with Hybrid graphics. In my experience that is the only reason for login loops. If you have a Laptop with Hybrid graphics card, then we have to take a different approach for resolving this issue, If you do not have a hybrid graphics Laptop then we have a different solution.

Comment: No, it's a desktop (HP Pavilion 500-413nl) with a GeForce GT 705 (I'm not sure about this acronym since I can't check it);  this video card has 1 GB of VRAM.

Comment: @RajatPandita That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: What driver did you install, exactly - and how?

Comment: I installed the one suggested in the tab named "Additional drivers" in "Software & Updates"; the recommended one was more recent and also the only one which had displayed "tested" (maybe 361? I don't remember). I just clicked "Apply changes".

Comment: @ Star OS. It makes perfect Sense if you ever owned an Optimus Powered Laptop or worked with one. I mean a laptop with Dual Graphics Card, Intel and Nvidia with Automatic Switching Capabilities.  The same login loop issue happens on that type of Laptop and the solution is completely different than what you are proposing.
So Please read between the lines, . You might have a lot of IT experience however you forget that one must first find out what we are dealing with before starting to assume and propose Random Solutions. The same issue can be caused by multiple reasons depending on hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reported the bug in Launchpad — actually someone else did this in June, I just added me in the queue, so that the bug become "Confirmed" from the "New" status.

(https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-361/+bug/1594586)

Comment: For now, the only solution is to disable "Secure boot"in BIOS/UEFI.

Answer (score -1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to text terminal and `rm ~/.Xauthority` file then reboot. It should help.

Comment: First we need to establish what graphics card we are dealing with! Hybrid graphics card (Optimus Powered Laptop), or a standard graphics Card. ! without that solution will not be accurate.

Comment: @dennisfen
It didn't help :(
I wrote the command, then entered, then pressed "Ctrl" +"Alt"+"Canc" to reboot…

Comment: ("Canc" is "Del")

Comment: @JKandy-drew did it show any errors when you tried to delete the file?

Comment: No, it didn't. It just showed me again the terminal (i.e. the "$" symbol after which you can write another command)